# LibGDX random OpenAL crash

Tags: java, libgdx, openal

before today everything was fine with the audio, and then today, from nowhere, my audio system just decided not to work ?

When i start my app i get this message :

```
AL lib: (EE) DoReset: Failed to initialize audio client: 0x887c0032
LwjglApplication: Couldn't initialize audio, disabling audio
org.lwjgl.openal.OpenALException: Invalid Device
    at org.lwjgl.openal.Util.checkALCError(Util.java:55)
    at org.lwjgl.openal.ALC10.alcCreateContext(ALC10.java:251)
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.init(AL.java:173)
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:143)
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:102)
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:206)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.audio.OpenALAudio.<init>(OpenALAudio.java:72)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:83)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:64)
    at com.uriopass.supergun.desktop.SupergunLauncher.main(SupergunLauncher.java:41)
```

It looks like i can't do anything to it. So i was wondering if there was a way to actually KNOW that i can't use sound and so disable it.